# Is there any public API to test Volley API?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-volley

I am new to Android and I am interested in looking into the Volley API for network requests. My question is how could I test my code? Is there a public service I could send requests to for my testing? JSON requests I mean.
My only intent is understanding the API not so much the actual data I get/use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. I used this a lot.
[JSON Test](http://www.jsontest.com/)